# How to create, handle and destory multiple windows at once?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I've heard that to create multiple windows in my C++ application, all I need to do is just make as many `HWND`s as I want, and for each one, use `CreateWindowEx()`, along with the appropriate windowclasses, etc.
I've managed that already, so that's not the problem.

Now, normally, I'd make this kind of a messageloop for my application:

```
MSG msg;
while(1)
{
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;
}
```

(That should be correct, yes?)

But now that I have 3 windows, my messageloop looks like this:

```
MSG msg;
while(1)
{
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) || PeekMessage(&msg, hConWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) || PeekMessage(&msg, hStatWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;
}
```

So it checks the messages for all the windows, right?

Now my question is, is this the correct way of getting messages for multiple windows?
Also, I've heard that using different `WndProc`s for different windows isn't good, is this true, and if so, why? (And how to use just one, if I want a bit different behavior for each window?)

And finally, how do I exit my application so that if one of the windows is closed (any window), all will be closed, appropriately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, ...` will do what you need. `msg` will receive handle of window where the message will need to be dispatched, so single API call is good for all existing windows out there.

> hWnd [in, optional]
>
> A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window must belong to the current thread.
>
> If hWnd is NULL, PeekMessage retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current
>   thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL (see the MSG
>   structure). Therefore if hWnd is NULL, both window messages and thread
>   messages are processed.

That is, you are OK to stay with your original message pumping loop, just not limit it to specific window.

The Qs:

> Now my question is, is this the correct way of getting messages for multiple windows?

A message loop, yours or someone's dispatches messages. You handle them on your window's `WndProc` without thinking too much who exactly delivers the messages and calls your `WndProc`. It works equally well for single window, and for multiple.

> Also, I've heard that using different WndProcs for different windows isn't good, is this true, and if so, why? (And how to use just one, if I want a bit different behavior for each window?)

Untrue.

> And finally, how do I exit my application so that if one of the windows is closed (any window), all will be closed, appropriately?

When `WM_QUIT` is posted in your example, the message loop breaks out. Then you are supposed to destroy windows and exit.

Comment: Is it possible for other windows than my own, to belong to the current thread?

Comment: Windows "belongs" to the thread where it was created, so if you created all them in one thread, then yes this single message pump will serve all of them. Passing `NULL` as the second argument will enable dispatching message even to windows that are not yours, such as and especially "service" windows like those belonging to COM subsystem.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause all kinds of problems if my `WndProc` would handle the messages of other windows?

Comment: Your `WndProc` will only be called for *your* messages. `DispatchMessage` is responsible for delivering to proper `WndProc`.

Comment: So the messageloop would _read_ all the messages from the current thread, but handle only the ones that belong to their respective `WndProc`s?

Comment: `PeekMessage` basically reads next message into `msg` variable, including window the message belongs to. `DispatchMessage` calls respective `WndProc` registered with that window. It is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll give you an upvote for that. But I still need answers for the last two of my questions; is it good practice to use multiple `WndProcs`, or should I somehow use just one (I have no idea how to implement that), and how do I set up the `WndProc`s so that when one of the windows closes, all of them will close?